Continuous piecewise linear (CPWL) function fitting a dataset for which each linear piece contains at least 3 points
Imagine a 2D dataset $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1,...,N}$ and a univariate continuous piecewise linear (CPWL) function composed of $K$ linear pieces $f$ such each point $i$ belongs to the segment $s(i) \in \{1,...,K\}$ and such that $f(x_i) = y_i$.
We can prove that there is an "equivalent" CPWL $g$ such that each segment can be extended by a line that connect at least two consecutive points.
Definition: By being "equivalent" to $f$, I mean that the point-to-segment allocation of $g$ is the same as $f$ and $g(x_i) = f(x_i) = y_i$.
My question is about the case of bivariate CPWL functions for 3D datasets $(x_i,y_i,z_i)_{i=1,...,N}$. For any CPWL function verifying $f(x_i,y_i) = z_i$, is there always an equivalent CPWL functions $g$ for which each linear piece can be extended by a plane that connect at least 3 points?
I have a strong intuition that this is the case as it seems impossible to find a counterexample, but I cannot find a way to prove it either.
